# Is the argout paradigm good practice in RenderScript?

Tags: renderscript

Reflection classes in RenderScript contain functions that execute the kernels. These functions follow the out argument paradigm- one of their arguments an Allocation in which output is stored.

Is there a reason this is better practice than *returning* the output Allocation? (Should I  follow suit and use out arguments in my RenderScript-related functions?)

For example, I have implemented the following helper class which wraps `ScriptC_gradient` and computes the gradient of a Bitmap. It *can* infer from the input Allocation what type the output Allocation should have, and thus hide the boilerplate necessary to set up the destination Allocation. Is there a reason to prefer one implementation of `compute()` over the other?

```java
public class Gradient {
    private RenderScript mRS;
    private ScriptC_gradient mScript;

    public Gradient(RenderScript RS) {
        mRS = RS;
        mScript = new ScriptC_gradient(mRS);
    }
    /* Out-argument implementation
     * 
     * This closely mirrors RenderScript's kernel functions, but
     * it requires the caller to write boilerplate to set up the 
     * destination Allocation.
     */
    public void compute(Allocation elevation, Allocation gradient) {
        mScript.invoke_setDimensions(elevation);
        mScript.forEach_root(elevation, gradient);
    }
    /* Allocation-returning implementation
     * 
     * This hides the boilerplate. 
     */
    public Allocation compute(Allocation elevation) {
        Allocation gradient = Allocation.createTyped(mRS, 
                new Type.Builder(mRS,Element.F32_2(mRS))
                   .setX(elevation.getType().getX())
                   .setY(elevation.getType().getY())
                   .create(),
                Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
        mScript.invoke_setDimensions(elevation);
        mScript.forEach_root(elevation, gradient);
        return gradient;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  yourScript.forEach_youKernel() cannot return an Allocation for output since it has no way to know what Allocation is to be used to write the output into unless its passed as an argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the reason to prefer the approach with the passed in Allocation for the output is memory reuse.  Creating allocations is expensive and should not be done more than necessary.

The second method would also cause problems for "tiling" where you do multiple kernel launches to each fill out a part of an output allocation.  As the output would be reallocated each time the previous contents would be lost (or have to be copied).